# Moodle hide turn editing off for students

Tags: moodle

I want to do with configuration settings

[image: Student can enable turn editing]

Please suggest the best possible way

Answer (score 2):

In order to hide this button for your students, you will want to edit the capabilities of their role.  In order to do this go to the navigation path "Site Administration->Users->Permissions->define roles" and select the role attributed to your students.

Now in order to hide the edit button, you will have to set all capabilities that are related to customisation of a course to prevent or prohibit.  This first list is the list of capabilities that I have seen online that should do what you want.  those are as follows:

-moodle/site:manageblocks
-moodle/course:manageactivities
-moodle/course:update

listed below are the ones I disabled in order to achieve this functionality.  However this list may include too many, so i would experiment with your site specifically.

-moodle/course:configurecustomfields 
-moodle/course:publish
-moodle/competency:coursecompetencymanage
-moodle/course:changelockedcustomfields 
-moodle/course:changesummary
-moodle/course:changeshortname 
-moodle/course:delete
-moodle/course:movesections 
-moodle/course:sectionvisibility
-moodle/course:tag 
-moodle/backup:backupcourse